# Commerce : products with 2 prices

Tags: commerce

In a Commerce project, the customer should be able to choose between 2 options with a radio field, for some products only, **with a different price for each option**. When a customer selects a radio option, the unit price should be changed accordingly and with ajax, and the line item updated I guess.

We also need that the admin enter PRICE A, PRICE B in 2 `commerce_price` fields when he creates new products, not by rule calculation neither  +90 or -100 as in [Commerce Pricing Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricing_attributes) (because prices vary a lot and having to calculate each price difference would be a source of errors).

At the moment the lone idea I got to configure this is :

- set a *line item field* with these radio options, shown in the add to cart form.
- Then or a pricing rule which detects if the 2nd price exists, and is selected ; sets the 2nd price as the unit price ?

Or programmatically, with some hook ? Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pricing rules** was the right track. In order to configure 2 main prices for a single product :

Add a 2nd price field to the product type:

[image: added a 2nd price field to my product type]

Add a boolean field to the corresponding *line item type*:

[image: boolean field to the corresponding line item]

In the Add to Cart form settings of this field (`admin/commerce/config/line-items/CUSTOM-line-item/fields/field_avec_aerien`), check  *Include this field on Add to Cart forms for line items of this type.*

Finally, in `admin/commerce/config/product-pricing/rules/manage/`, create (or clone & edit) a new **pricing rule** which set the unit price to 2nd price amount, when the boolean is checked by the customer in the add to cart form.

[image: pricing rule which set the unit price to 2nd price amount]

Pricing rules are very powerful, indeed !

Comment: Nice, this puzzeled me for a while now. There is some more reading on pricing rules here (I needed Google to figure out what they were): https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-pricing-rules-screencast

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should go for product attribute.

You've got a few tutorial about it on the drupalcommerce website :

- https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-attributes-variations
- https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-displays
- https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/cart

Lucky you, one the commerce guys (Randy Fay) also make a video where he briefly talk about it : http://vimeo.com/user5912539 (can't remember which one :x)

Comment: Thanks. Anyway this does not answer my question. In order to change the price with an attribute, it's possible to use *pricing attributes* module, but as explained above, it doesn't fit this specific case.